Configuring fancyhdr with a report document class
I am trying to configure the fancyhdr package with a report document and it appears that the first page of each \chapter does not get a footer.
I understand the \part section type is not expected to contain text (it's centered on its page), but the chapter is implemented like a section and appears at the top left of a page. It is also necessary to use a chapter in the appendix to avoid misnumbering.
Either I don't know how Latex expected the report to be used with chapters, or I have not configured my footers correctly to ensure they appear on all pages.
I would be grateful for some guidance with the MRE below:
\documentclass[letterpaper]{report}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.65in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=red,breaklinks=true}

\title{My Title}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle

  \tableofcontents

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \fancyhf{}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyfoot{}
  \fancyfoot[L]{Left side}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
  \fancyfoot[R]{Right side}

  \part{My Part}
  \chapter{My Chapter}
  \ipsum
  \newpage
  \ipsum
  \section{My Section}
  \ipsum
  \newpage
  \ipsum
  \chapter{Another Chapter}
  \ipsum
  \newpage
  \ipsum

  \begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Some Note}
    \ipsum
    \chapter{Another Note}
    \ipsum
    \newpage
    \ipsum
    \chapter{Yet Another Note}
    \ipsum
    \newpage
    \ipsum
  \end{appendices}
\end{document}


The first page of each chapter has an automatic \thispagestyle{plain}.  The easy solution is to modify plain style, and the easiest way to do that is \makeatletter \let\ps@plain=\ps@fancy \makeatother.

... unless you're using headers, too, of course, in which case you probably don't want those on the first page of chapters (which is why the style is different).
